# git issue with branch/HEAD/master/origin

Tags: git

I am having an issue with git and I m totally lost as I dont have any experience with it at all.

I am attaching a screenshot that describes the issue:

How can I make the "new_master" (refactoring the last two steps of register in store) the current remote master/origin, without loosing the history BEFORE this ?

Thank you very much

[Current git status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uvI5.png)

Comment: Probably you need to merge `new_master` into `master`.

Comment: Yes, maybe you just need to `merge` both branches

Comment: As long as it’s in git, it’s very difficult to actually lose data. Just don’t delete the repo, or remove all references.